# Laravel Query Builder order by relationship field

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I'm trying to order by a relationship field in the following way:

```
Post::with(['comments' => function($query) {
    $query->orderBy('some_comment_field', 'desc');
}]);
```

But this doesn't work. How can I do this?

I use Laravel 5.8.

Comment: `withAggregate` is another elegant option, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72277299). I had issues using join and distinct together in some complex queries, but `withAggregate` method solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to order by a comments fields, you should add it to the main select using join:

```
Post::with(['comments'])->join('comments','posts.id','comments.post_id')
->select(['posts.*','comments.some_comment_field'])
->orderby('comments.some_comment_field', 'desc')->get();
```

you can omit the eager loading comments and select the comments field you want, you can also use aliases to get clear columns names

Answer (score 0):

Example 1

```
// in post model
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'post_id', 'id');
}

// in post controller
Post::with(['comments' => function($query) {
    $query->orderBy('date', 'desc');
}])->get();
```

Example 2

```
// in post model
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'post_id', 'id')
        ->orderBy('date', 'desc');
}

// in post controller
Post::with('comments')->get();
```