# How to get records order by nested relation's column in Laravel?

Tags: sql, laravel

I'm using Laravel 9.
To clarify my question I will explain the models also the relations between them.

The first model is `LicenseSubmission` which has a `one to many` relationship with `LicenseForm` model:

```
class LicenseSubmission extends Model
{

    public function licenseForm(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(LicenseForm::class);
    }
}
```

Also, `LicenseForm` model has a `one to many` relationship with `Department` model:

```
class LicenseForm extends Model
{

    public function department(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Department::class);
    }
  
}
```

Now I want to get `license_submissions` order by its related department's title.

How to do that?

If you can answer this question, there is no difference between Eloquent code and Raw SQL.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Order by relationship column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38261546/order-by-relationship-column)

Comment: Seems like a duplicate, but might be helpful to show the relationships between these three models as well as how the relationships are being accessed. Lazy vs eager loading, etc. Show your actual query code.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```php
LicenseSubmission::with('licenseForm.department')
    ->orderBy('licenseForm.department.title')
    ->get();
```